# If $(z-2)/(z+2)$ is purely imaginary, find $z$ that satisfies this condition?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> If $(z-2)/(z+2)$ is purely imaginary, then what is the value of $z$ that satisfies this condition?

I am troubled solving this equation for a long time. I tried to put $z = a + i b$ and then I got $(a-2+ib)(a+2+ib)$ is imaginary.

Not sure how to go now? Thank youvery much.

Comment: Multiply out and put the real part equal to $0$

Comment: mark bennet - thank you very much, i get it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{a-2+ib}{a+2+ib} = \frac{(a-2+ib)(a+2-ib)}{(a+2-ib)(a+2-ib)}$$

Now, simplify the expression, and remember how $(x+iy)(x-iy)=x^2+y^2$ is a real number. Therefore, you will get something like

$$\frac{\text{something} + (\text{something else})\cdot i}{\text{some real number}}$$

which is the same as

$$\frac{\text{something}}{\text{some real number}} + \frac{\text{something else}}{\text{some real number}}\cdot i$$

Comment: thank you very much! in this question we will put the real part as zero

Comment: @gilly Exactly.

Comment: wolfram alpha does not show a circle : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Re+((z-2)+%2F+(z%2B2))+%3D+0

Comment: @gilly Wolfram alpha assumes $z$ is a real number.

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to see that if $x$ is purely imaginary, then $x + \bar{x} = 0$

$$\frac{z-2}{z+2} + \frac{\bar{z}-2}{\bar{z}+2} = 0$$

Assume $z \neq -2$, then on solving you have:

$$z\bar z -2 \bar z + 2z -4 + z\bar z -2 z + 2\bar z -4 =0 \\
z\bar z = 4$$

Or that $|z| = 2$. This is a circle with radius $2$ and centre origin. Obviously note that $z = -2$ is **not a solution**.

Answer (score 2):

Let $0 \ne b \in \mathbb R$

\begin{align}
   \frac{z-2}{z+2} &= bi \\
   z-2 &= bzi+2bi \\
   (1-bi)z&= 2(1+bi) \\
   z &= 2\frac{1+bi}{1-bi} \\
   z &= 2\dfrac{(1-b^2)+2bi}{1+b^2}
\end{align}

Comment: We can say $z = 2 (\cos(t) + \sin(t))$ from last eqn. Nice one!

Comment: @samjoe How about  $z = 2 (\cos(t) + i \sin(t))$?

Comment: oops I meant that only :P

Answer (score 1):

Putting $z=a+ib$, with $z\neq-2$, is a correct way to start. Then, you get \begin{align}\frac{z-2}{z+2}&=\frac{z-2}{(a+2)+ib}=\frac{(a-2)+ib}{(a+2)+ib}\cdot\frac{(a+2)-ib}{(a+2)-ib}\\[0.2cm]&=\frac{(a-2)(a+2)+b^2+ib(a+2-a+2)}{(a+2)^2+b^2}=\underbrace{\frac{(a-2)(a+2)+b^2}{(a+2)^2+b^2}}_{=\text{ real part }=0}+i\frac{4b}{(a+2)^2+b^2}\end{align} So, you get the equation $$(a-2)(a+2)+b^2=0\iff a^2+b^2=2^2 \iff |z|=2$$ which gives a set of possible solutions.