# If the number z-2/z+2 is purely imaginary then find the value of mod(z)

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried taking $\frac{z-2}{z+2}=ik$ and solving, but all I got in the end was $(x-2)^2+y^2/(x+2)^2+y^2=k^2$. I'm not sure what to do after this. In this question, z is a complex number. I'd appreciate help. This is my first time posting here, so I apologize in advance for any formatting issues.

Comment: What is mod(x)?

Comment: Sorry, it means modulus of z

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $(z-2)/(z+2)$ is purely imaginary, find $z$ that satisfies this condition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481092/if-z-2-z2-is-purely-imaginary-find-z-that-satisfies-this-condition)

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that for a pure imaginary number, conjugation is the same as negation.

$$\frac{\bar z-2}{\bar z+2}= -\frac{z-2}{z+2}$$ Now cross multiply. 
$$z\bar z+2\bar z-2z-4=-z\bar z+2\bar z-2z+4$$
So $$2z\bar z=8$$ and $z\bar z=4$. But $|z|^2=z\bar z$. Hence the modulus is $2$.

Comment: I'm sorta confused. What you said in the first statement, if z=x+iy, wouldn't it become false?

Comment: @IshanDubey, I don't follow your question. I'm using that $\alpha=(z-2)/(z+2)$ is pure imaginary, so that $\bar\alpha=-\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, $a-b$ is the vector from $b$ to $a$ and $arg\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\arg(a)-\arg(b)$, is the angle between the vector $a$ and $b$. Then $\frac{z-2}{z+2}$ is purely imaginary implies that the angle between  the vector joining $z$ and $-2$, and the vector joining $z$ and $2$, is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, as argument of any imaginary number is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Now you can see that, this condition implies $z$ lies on the circumfurence of the circle with diameter whose endpoints are $2$ and $-2$.

Comment: I'm confused. If z=x+iy, that makes arg(z-2/z+2) = tan^-1(y/x-2)-tan^-1(y/x+2) right? So how are the angles between both vectors 90

Comment: because $arg\left(\frac{z-2}{z+2}\right)=arg(ik)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can write:

$$\frac{\text{z}-2}{\text{z}+2}=\frac{\left(\text{z}-2\right)\cdot\overline{\text{z}+2}}{\left(\text{z}+2\right)\cdot\overline{\text{z}+2}}=\frac{\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)-2+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)\cdot i\right)\cdot\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+2-\Im\left(\text{z}\right)\cdot i\right)}{\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+2\right)^2+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)}\tag1$$

Finding:

$$\Re\left(\frac{\text{z}-2}{\text{z}+2}\right)=\frac{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)-4}{\left(\Re\left(\text{z}\right)+2\right)^2+\Im\left(\text{z}\right)}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)-4=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)=4\tag2$$

And we know that:

$$\left|\text{z}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)}=\sqrt{4}=2\tag3$$

---

In general for $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}\space\wedge\space\text{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\Re\left(\frac{\text{z}-\text{n}}{\text{z}+\text{n}}\right)=0$, gives:

$$\Re\left(\frac{\text{z}-\text{n}}{\text{z}+\text{n}}\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\Re^2\left(\text{z}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}\right)=\text{n}^2\space\implies\space\left|\text{z}\right|=\text{n}\tag4$$